# Unable to update user profile form in angular 4

Tags: angular, form-submit

I want to submit user prfile form back to server using api but it is not updating, submit function is not calling 
but here I do not know what I am doing worng.
If debugging and checking on log data sometime it is showing data sometime not.
Here is the my Form code HTML

```
<form [formGroup]='updateProfileForm' (ngSubmit)='onSubmit(updateProfileForm.value)'>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                <label class="control-label " for="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='name'>
                                <app-field-error-display [displayError]="this.validationService.isFieldValid(updateProfileForm,'name')">
                                </app-field-error-display>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                <label class="control-label " for="name">Date of Birth</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='dob' id='dob' value="{{ dob | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy' }}" [readonly]="true">
                                <!-- <app-field-error-display [displayError]="this.validationService.isFieldValid(updateProfileForm,'dob')">
                                </app-field-error-display> -->
                                <span class='error-msg'></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='email'>
                                <app-field-error-display [displayError]="this.validationService.isFieldValid(updateProfileForm,'email')">
                                </app-field-error-display>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
                                <!-- <label class="control-label">Code</label> -->
                                <!-- <div class="input-group"> -->
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  formControlName='code' id ="txtVerifyPhoneCode"(keypress)="this.validationService.checkNumber($event)">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  formControlName='phone' id ="txtVerifyPhone"(keypress)="this.validationService.checkNumber($event)">
                                <!-- <label class="control-label">Phone</label> -->

                            </div>

                                <!-- <div class="input-group-btn"> -->
                                <button type="button" id="verifymebutton" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" (click) ="sendOTPmain1()">Verify</button>
                             <!-- </div></div> -->
                             <!-- </div> -->
                                <!-- <span class="button" *ngIf="varified"><br> -->
                                    <i class="fa fa-check main-content__checkmark success pull-right" id="checkmark1" style="font-size: 30px;" *ngIf="varified"></i>

                                    <!-- </span> -->
                                <!-- <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <ng-template #NotVarified>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="openOTPModel" (click)="sendOTPmain()" >Verify</button>
                                    </ng-template></div> -->

                                <app-field-error-display [displayError]="this.validationService.isFieldValid(updateProfileForm,'phone')">
                                </app-field-error-display>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group label-floating div_gender">

                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <span class="control-label gender_row">Gender&nbsp;</span>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="1" formControlName='gender' [checked]="gender===1">Male
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="2" formControlName='gender' [checked]="gender===2">Female
                                </label>
                                <!-- <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="3" formControlName='gender' [checked]="gender===3">Other
                                </label> -->
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="3" formControlName='gender' [checked]="gender===4">Don't want to disclose
                                </label>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating select_lang">
                                <label class="control-label">Country</label>
                                <select class='form-control' name='country_id' id="country_id" formControlName='country_id' (change)="selectedCountry($event)" >
                                    <option *ngFor='let country of countryList' [ngValue]="country._id">{{ country.country }}</option>
                                    <app-field-error-display [displayError]="this.validationService.isFieldValid(updateProfileForm,'country_id')">
                                    </app-field-error-display>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating select_lang">
                                <label class="control-label">Language</label>
                                <select class='form-control' name='language_id' formControlName='language_id'>
                                    <option *ngFor='let language of languageList' [ngValue]="language._id">{{ language.language }}</option>
                                    <app-field-error-display [displayError]="this.validationService.isFieldValid(updateProfileForm,'language_id')">
                                    </app-field-error-display>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating select_lang">
                                <label class="control-label">Field</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="category_id" formControlName="category_id" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
                                    <!-- <option value="" d>Select Category (required)</option> -->
                                    <option *ngFor='let surveyCategory of surveyCategoryList' [ngValue]="surveyCategory._id" >{{ surveyCategory.category }}</option>
                                    <app-field-error-display [displayError]="this.validationService.isFieldValid(updateProfileForm,'category_id')">
                                    </app-field-error-display>
                               </select>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating select_lang">
                                <label class="control-label">Profession</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="profession_id" formControlName="profession_id">
                                     <!-- <option value="" >Select Category (required)</option> -->
                                    <option *ngFor='let profession of ProfessionList' [ngValue]="profession._id">{{ profession.profession }}</option>
                                    <app-field-error-display [displayError]="this.validationService.isFieldValid(updateProfileForm,'profession_id')">
                                    </app-field-error-display>
                               </select>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group label-floating select_lang">
                                <label class="control-label">View Video</label>
                                <!-- <select class="form-control" name="view_video" formControlName="videoviewstatus"> -->
                                    <!-- <toggle [on]="true" (toggled)="showMessage($event)"></toggle>       -->
                                    <!-- <mat-slide-toggle [formControl]="autoRenew">Auto-Renew</mat-slide-toggle>  -->
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group label-floating" >
                                <!-- <label class="control-label">Video Status</label><br/>
                                <ui-switch labelOn="Yes" labelOff="No" formControlName='videoviewstatus' [checked]="videoviewstatus===true" ></ui-switch>
                               -->
                               <!-- <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-checkbox" [id]="videoviewstatus">
                               <span  [ngClass]="videoviewstatus ? 'toggler on' : 'toggler on off'">&nbsp;</span> -->

                             <label class="switch" formControlName= 'videoviewstatus'>
                                 <!-- <div ng-if="videostatus = true">  -->
                                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" checked=""> 
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            <!-- </div>  -->
                              </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="verifymyphone()" id="updateProfile" value="Update">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Here is submit function in ts.
//update profile

```
onSubmit = function (data) {
    if (!this.updateProfileForm.valid) {
        this.validationService.validateAllFormFields(this.updateProfileForm);
        return;
    }
    var dob = $('#dob').val();
    if (dob == '') {
        $('.error-msg').html('Date of birth field is required').css('color', '#a94442');
        return;
    } else {
        var dt = dob.split('-');
        data.dob = new Date(dt[2], "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec".indexOf(dt[1]) / 3, dt[0]);
    }
    if (!this.select_country) {

        this.select_country = $('#country_id :selected').text();
    }
    if (!this.select_field) {

        this.select_field = $('#category_id :selected').text();

    }
    if (!this.select_profession) {

        this.select_profession = $('#profession_id :selected').text();

    }
    if (this.current_location.toLowerCase() != this.select_country.toLowerCase()) {
        $.growl.error({
            title: 'Error',
            message: "Selected country is different from your current location"
        });
        return;
    }
    var word = this.checkCensoredWordsSingle(data.name)
    if (word) {
        $.growl.error({
            title: 'Error',
            message: "Name should not contain any censored word like : " + word
        });
        return;
    }

    data.phone = "" + data.phone;
    data.gender = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();

    // if()


    //  if(data.videoviewstatus==true)
    // {

    // }


    $("#updateProfile").val("UPDATING...").attr("disabled", true);
    this.authService.updateProfile(data).subscribe(data => {
    debugger;
        if (data.success) {
            $.growl.notice({
                title: 'Success',
                message: data.message
            });
        } else {
            $.growl.error({
                title: 'Error',
                message: data.error
            });
        }
        $("#updateProfile").val("UPDATE").attr("disabled", false);
    });
}
```

and here is the service.ts file code goes here

```
// Update profile
updateProfile = function (data) {
  debugger;
    return this.http.put(this.api_url + 'update', JSON.stringify(data), this.getAuthHeaderOption()).map(res => res.json());
}
```

my view looks like below 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaOQT.png)

Comment: the `(click)` on your submit button might be preventing the `(ngSubmit)` on the `<form>` tag from firing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but sorry I did not catch it

Comment: why are you using jQuery?!

Comment: Please anyone can suggest me ?

Comment: @JamieRees Please suggest me what I can use instead of JQuery?

Comment: @JamieRees Here I am using JQuery to detect user data if not detected in formdata

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga you don't need anything instead of JQuery, Angular already have all the functionality and much more.

Comment: So I don't need to use JQuery

Comment: Yes, refer to the Forms Guide https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: Are you using function instead of class and methods in ts file

Comment: Sorry, What function about are you talking?

Comment: @JasonWhite what  should I do with the form tag ?